# How do I publish my flutter application in Visual studio?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, visual-studio-code

I made a simple app with visual studio code and I want to publish ( what i mean is to turn it into apk ) How can I do this?

Comment: When you run the app, an apk is generated and that is what runs on the emulator or your connected device. Have you not run you app?

Comment: Flutter run from the vscode terminal does the same thing.

Comment: all above comments are Ok. if you wnat to build an apk run `flutter build apk`  readmore here https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Comment: Yes I runned my app but I wondered how something like setup could be